# Error Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for ios project. React Native

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I have a macbook pro m1 and I am getting the above error when trying npx react-native init. I have followed the react native documentation for environment set up. I tried to install pod via brew, however, still the same error. What is the issue? I see a lot of people having the same issue, but there is no clear explanation or solution for it? Please help

✔ Processing template
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./test/ios && pod install".
CocoaPods documentation: https://cocoapods.org/

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.

when I tried to run ios:

BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/patrickbelan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-gqoaknolitrwejedppjzybscmama/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/main.o /Users/patrickbelan/Desktop/react/test/ios/test/main.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'test' from project 'test')
CompileC /Users/patrickbelan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-gqoaknolitrwejedppjzybscmama/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o /Users/patrickbelan/Desktop/react/test/ios/test/AppDelegate.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'test' from project 'test')
(2 failures)

Comment: Please, provide more information about the issue you are facing. I mean **logs, errors, Podfile, etc.**

Comment: hi here is the more information. I tried to c/p the whole log from terminal but it is too big. it does not aloud me to post it. hopes this helps

Answer (score 0):

[Xcode Location window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lf8F.png)

How about trying to further ensure with  Xcode that there is a valid command-line tool chosen. Go to Xcode Preferences » Location and selected Xcode version from the Command Line Tools select list if its blank.

And then run cd ./yourAppName/ios && pod install inside that app folder